# WebApi routing - many GET methods

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have the following (standard) WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and the following api controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/Books
    [Route("")]
    public IQueryable<string> GetBooks()
    {
        return null;
    }

    // GET api/Books/5
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBook(int id)
    {

        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("{id:int}/details")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetBookDetail(int id)
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("abc")]
    public IQueryable<string> GetBooksByGenre(string genre)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("~api/authors/{authorId}/books")]
    public IQueryable<string> GetBooksByAuthor(int authorId)
    {
        return null;

    }
}
```

It found appropriate method when I call

- `api/books`
- `api/books/1`
- `api/books/1/details`

but it can't find `api/books/abc`.

If I change `[Route("abc")]` to `[Route("{genre}")]` it works (pass abc as genre parameter).

But I need to have many GET methods with different names.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
// GET api/Books/genres/horror
[Route("genres/{genre}")]
public IQueryable<string> GetBooksByGenre(string genre)
{
    return null;
}
```

Or even

```
// GET api/genres/horror/books
[Route("~api/genres/{genre}/books")]
public IQueryable<string> GetBooksByGenre(string genre)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thank you, but really I need POST methods :) I thought it would be the same, but it does not work properly for POST :(

Comment: No where in your OP indicated you needed POST. Use `HttpPost` Attribute on methods that are POST. Read up on [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes)

Comment: I ask here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35975701/webapi-routing-many-post-methods