# WebApi routing - many POST methods

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I have WebAPI 2 application. How can I specify 2 or more POST methods?

I have the following WebApiConfig:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

and API Controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    [Route("Post1")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IQueryable<string> Post1(string str)
    {
        return null;
    }

    [Route("Post2")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IQueryable<string> Post2(int id)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It works neither I call:

```
/api/books/post1
```

nor

```
/api/books/post2
```

why and how to solve it?

**UPDATE:**

Problem is solved, problem was in simple types as parameters. I get 404 error

> Message=No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI
>   'http://localhost:37406/api/books/post1'.

with request:

```
POST http://localhost:37406/api/books/post1 HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:35979
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

{
    "str" : "Fffff"
}
```

and code:

```
    [Route("Post1")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post1(string str)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }


    [Route("Post2")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post2(int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }
```

but it works fine with complex type:

```
   [HttpPost]
   [Route("Post1")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post1(Book book)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Post2")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post2(Book book)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }



public class Book
{
    public int BookId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Genre { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you Nkosi

**UPDATE 2:**

but it works when parameter is marked with [FromBody]

```
    [Route("Post1")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post1([FromBody]string str)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }


    [Route("Post2")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post2([FromBody]int id)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse();
    }
```

(for complex types it's unnecessary). Logically, but Route error confused :)

Comment: What tool are you using to test your POSTs

Comment: Fiddler http://www.magicscreenshot.com/jpg/ne7mCjKYS04.html

Comment: No Problem. It can work with simple types if you use [FromBody] or [FromUrl] attribute on parameter to let the framework know where to look for the parameter. Check [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt taken from [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#add-routes)

> **HTTP Methods**
>
> Web API also selects actions based on the HTTP method of the request
>   (GET, POST, etc). By default, Web API looks for a case-insensitive
>   match with the start of the controller method name. For example, a
>   controller method named PutCustomers matches an HTTP PUT request.
>
> You can override this convention by decorating the mathod with any the
>   following attributes:

```
[HttpDelete]
[HttpGet]
[HttpHead]
[HttpOptions]
[HttpPatch]
[HttpPost]
[HttpPut]
```

The following example maps the CreateBook method to HTTP POST requests.

```
[Route("api/books")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage CreateBook(Book book) { ... }
```

Example:

```
public class Book {
    public int BookId{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public string Author{get;set;}
    public string Genre{get;set;}
}

[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/books
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> Get() { ... }

    // GET api/books/5
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public Book Get(int id) { ... }

    // POST api/books
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post1(Book book) { ... }

    // POST api/books/alternate
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("alternate")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Post2(Book book) { ... }
}
```

Sample POST Body for `Post1`

```
POST http://localhost:35979/api/books HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:35979
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 80

{
    "Title":"Scary Book",
    "Author":"John Doe",
    "Genre":"Horror" 
}
```

Sample POST Body for `Post2`

```
POST http://localhost:35979/api/books/alternate HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:35979
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 85

{
    "Title":"Fantastic Book",
    "Author":"Jane Doe",
    "Genre":"Fantasy" 
}
```

Comment: Yes. You can any amount you want once their paths don't conflict

Comment: Those 2 posts conflict with each other as well as the template/route used.

Comment: @Nikosi Which conflict? seems, it does not work with simple types.

Comment: It can work with simple types. use `[FromBody]` or `[FromUrl]` attribute on parameter to let the framework know where to look for the parameter. Check [Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). You'll see where you made the mistake

Comment: with `[FromBody]` it works. Spent 3 hours on such trivial thing :(